# twitter-bootstrap grid system columns for less than 768px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've used bootstrap grid system in a project.

I want to have:

- 2 columns for less than 768px and more than 384px
- 1 column for less than 384px

Edit: How can i make something like this? **col-xxs-12** (Django template example):

```
<div class="row">
    {% for item in product %}
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 **col-xxs-12**">
            <div class="well">
                {{item.model}}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far and explain how you got stuck?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints You can create and download a customizable version of Bootstrap, changing the break-points as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

as a solution

```
<style>
  @media (max-width: 384px) {
    .hidden-xxs {
      display: none;
    }

    .visible-xxs {
      display: block;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 385px) {
    .visible-xxs {
      display: none;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="row hidden-xxs">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    visible on less than 768px
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6">
    visible on less than 768px
  </div>
</div>

<div class="visible-xxs">
  less than 384px
</div>
```